# Python Damerau-Levenshtein distance with variable costs (a.k.a. generalized D-L)

Tags: library, python

Is there a python package which supports the [Damerau-Levenshtein-Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) with

- support for any type of array, especially integers
- weights for transposition, insertion, deletion and substitution, such that f.ex. 1 insertion counts as much as 3 deletions?

Some common libraries

- https://github.com/gfairchild/pyxDamerauLevenshtein has a fast distance function, yet no weights, and only works on strings
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance/0.2 which (according to PyPi) works with any hashable object, yet seemingly does not support weights
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0 is a Levenshtein-distance, which offers no transpositions
- https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish offers a range of metrics, including Damerau-Levenshtein, but no weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a library (a cython one would be even more preferable), but the code at http://mwh.geek.nz/2009/04/26/python-damerau-levenshtein-distance/ can be converted to variable costs pretty easily, by replacing the `+ 1` with the weights:

```
delcost = oneago[y] + weight_deletion
addcost = thisrow[y - 1] + weight_addition
subcost = oneago[y - 1] + ((seq1[x] != seq2[y]) * weight_substition)
thisrow[y] = min(delcost, addcost, subcost)
# This block deals with transpositions
if (x > 0 and y > 0 and seq1[x] == seq2[y - 1]
    and seq1[x-1] == seq2[y] and seq1[x] != seq2[y]):
    thisrow[y] = min(thisrow[y], (twoago[y - 2] + 1 * weight_transposition))
```